# Name of this notion in a total order?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology, order-theory, programming

Let me start with a prototypical situation, with $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. I'd like to divide $S$ into the "smaller" and "bigger" parts, by specifying the boundary $t \in \mathbb{R}$, as (i) $(-\infty, t] \cap S$ and $(t, +\infty) \cap S$, and (ii) in its dual(?) way, into $(-\infty, t) \cap S$ and $[t, +\infty) \cap S$. Forgetting everything about $\mathbb{R}$, cardinality, topology, etc, except it's a totally ordered set, do these two partitions have names?

Now let us be general, by replacing $\mathbb{R}$ with any totally ordered set $T$. Consider partitioning $S$ into two disjoint sets $= A \amalg B$, such that for $\forall a \in A$ and $\forall b \in B$, $a < b$ and $a \le t \le b$, where $t \in T$. There're two ways if $t \in S$. In words, in the above case (i) the smaller part is maximal among the subsets of $S$ for which $t$ is an upper bound.

*My question is*: do such bisections have names in order theory? (They must be final or initial, but I think I can google it once I know the names.)

**EDIT**: I'd like names that distinguish the two boundary conditions.

Background: This question was inspired when studying the Python language module "bisect". [1] There a sorted array (or a vector, and in Python a sorted "list") `a` is considered.

One can think of the array `a` as e.g. $a: [0, 1, ..., n] \to \mathbb{Z}$, an increasing function. (Read [] as {}, sorry. \{ \} didn't work.) Let $A := (-\infty, t],$  then Python's `bisect_right` returns $a^{-1}(A)$ and its complement $a^{-1}(\mathbb{Z} \setminus A)$.

In programming, the appearance of these two bisections seems natural and ubiquitous, e.g. as a for-loop boundary condition. So they IMHO deserve names.

[1] Python doc: [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html).
In fact, I [proposed its revision](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/95552), but the maintainer rejected it.

Comment: Order ideal, order filter, down-set, up-set, among others

Comment: My question seems to have been ambiguous; I'd like to distinguish the two cases. Yep, *both* $(-\infty, t) \cap S$ and $ (-\infty, t] \cap S$ are indeed downsets \*of $S$\*...

Comment: [Generalizations od Dedekind cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut#Generalizations) might be useful.

Comment: At least for $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$, Dedekind cuts do not distinguish $<$ and $\le$...

Comment: Oh, I see.  Well, in the case of a finite poset (or one with a minimal element) I might call $(-\infty, t]$ the lower interval of $t$ and $(-\infty, t)$ the open lower interval of $t$.  But I think the fundamental answer is "there is no name for this so standard that you won't have to explain it, so choose something reasonable and make a clear definition".

Comment: Some relevant terms: principal ideal, principal filter, initial segment, final segment.

Comment: If $t \in S$, they're indeed principal.